# Printing php tags and variable assignment as text

Tags: php, html, string, printing

Assume I have this text:

```
<?php

  $my_first_word = 'hi there';

  echo $my_first_word;

?>
```

And I want to print it out to the screen, only problem is when I put all the text inside a `print"";`

It doesn't actually print the php tags and etc, I want it to actually be outputted on the browser as text.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do =/

Comment: I am trying to print out that peice of text to the browser. That is all. But when i print it out, it takes the PHP tags and treats it like an actual tag where i would open a php document, i just want it to be treated as plain text, and be outputted.

Comment: You mean that it literally shows you "echo $my_first_word;" ?

Comment: yes it literaly shows that, and it literaly shows the tags and everything there too

Comment: I guess `echo "$" . "my_first_word";` isn't what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as text:

```
echo '<?php

$my_first_word = \'hi there\';

echo $my_first_word;

?>';
```

as html:

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars('<?php

$my_first_word = \'hi there\';

echo $my_first_word;

?>'));
```

Do note [the use of `'`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for quoting ([otherwise](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) the variables would not be literals), as well as the therefore escaped `'` char inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities
```

For string to print new line add this:

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($string));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: NO, i told you clearly that i want the tags and EVERYTHING there too, read the comments carefully please.

Comment: Anyways, your answer doesnt add any line breaks or anything.

Comment: You can nl2br to convert new line or /n into <br />. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($string));`

Answer (score 1):

```
$expand = 'appear';
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either'; // Outputs: Variables $expand
echo "Variables do not $expand $either"; // Outputs: Variables appear
```

Comment: this is important little stuff for performance when U have big big amount of date. use most of the time single quotes like echo 'text'.$var.'text';

Comment: Ah okay, can i ask, how and why does using single quotes improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try:

```
print sprintf("%s", htmlspecialchars($my_first_word));
```